# Getting a list of header columns where the value is true

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas, time-and-attendance

I apologise if this question appears simple, but I'm having trouble making it work.
[image: problem]

I just want to know what days were each employee absent in the column G (the last column), for example I want it like:
[image: expected solution]

I tried to apply some MATCH/FILTER and ARRAYFORMULA formulas, but did not crack the puzzle. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTER()`.

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($B$1:$F$1,B2:F2=1)),"")
```

[image]

For dynamic spill array, use-

```
=BYROW(B2:INDEX(F2:F,COUNTA(A2:A)),
 LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($B$1:$F$1,x=1)),"")))
```

[image]

Divide the results into cells.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(
 BYROW(B2:INDEX(F2:F,COUNTA(A2:A)),
 LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER($B$1:$F$1,x=1)),""))), ", ", 0),""))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`IFERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`COUNTA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`FILTER`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

Comment: Thanks @Osm for adding references of functions.